# batch script or python program to edit string in xml tags

Tags: python, batch-file, xml, string

I am looking to write a program that searches for the  tags in an xml document and changes the string between the tags from localhost to manager. The tag might appear in the xml document multiple times, and the document does have a definite path. Would python or vbscript make the most sense for this problem? And can anyone provide a template so I can get started? That would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't try touch an XML document in any language that doesn't have a decent parser.  Using a regular expression for xml/xhtml will [drive you insane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).  If the language has an XML parser (both vbscript, and python do) then just pick your favorite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [batch script or python program to edit string in xml tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198416/batch-script-or-python-program-to-edit-string-in-xml-tags)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple thing, like changing a few strings here and there, you might be able to do everything with a python regexp, check here:

- http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

For everything more complex, I would suggest using something like Beautiful Soup:

- http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html

It's a bit outdated, but contains everything you would ever need...

I agree this belongs to stackoverflow.com, as it's a programming question.

Comment: @marr75 Yeah, BeautifulSoup rocks. I would not avoid regex, though, if it's something simple - it might be a good choice if you need to e.g. change all occurences of `Spanish` to `French` or something similar. But definitively agree for anything more complex, regex is probably just going to give more headaches then help anything... There's that famous saying:  

Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I’ll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems.
  
--Jamie Zawinski, in comp.lang.emacs

Comment: Yeah, regexes are quite problematic, for me it is mostly because of their non-readability - try to read your own regex in one month - not quite easy. Everyone should try pyparsing, it save me loads of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you go straight to lxml library for python and don't look back. The regex manipulation of xml can have terrible consequences, and BeautifulSoup, although quite popular, is officially abandoned.

`lxml` is quite powerfull, fast and efficient. For your task, it is sufficient to write:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.fromstring(content)
elements = doc.findall('tags_to_modify')
for el in elements:
    el.text = your_replacement_function(el.text)
print etree.tostring(doc)
```

You can find a lot of help in lxml's documentation:
http://lxml.de/

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, since your answer is still good, but BeautifulSoup is not abandoned. BeautifulSoup is open source and is still being supported. It relies on a parser library that is not available in python 3.0 (which a relatively small percent of users run). In the future, a python 3.0 version of BeautifulSoup will allow pluggable parsers.

Comment: I was referring to this post: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html from which I got the impression that people won't put an effort to port it to python 3.0. Sorry for being negligent.

Comment: No negligence involved, the post has to be read pretty carefully and then investigated afterward to get the full story.